How to get Targus Dock120 up and running in Fedora39
I am using a Targus Dock120 docking station, or better said, I would like to use it. Unfortunately, I cannot succeed in making it work.
I tried to access the download page for drivers from Targus, but unfortunately, the homepage just wont open and I cannot access the drivers (yes, I tried different browsers and machines).
Then, I thought maybe the DisplayLink drivers are missing. So, I followed this tutorial from this reddit post. However, I did not succeed. The driver I downloaded from Github is the x86_64.rpm
Unfortunately, it still does not work. I just tried to sudo systemctl start displaylink
which resulted in
Failed to start displaylink.service: Unit displaylink.service not found.
Does anyone have any clue whether the DisplayLink drivers should be sufficient in order to get the docking station up and runnind, or whether I need additional drivers?
If the DisplayLink drivers are sufficient...how can I correctly install them?

Just to check it's all about display handling. Can you verify its other features are available? Most proeminently, do you get a new Ethernet interface when the dock is plugged in?

Also it appears Targus thinks Linux means Ubuntu: https://us.targus.com/blogs/discover-targus/targus-releases-r-5-6-1-for-ubuntu-linux . Anyway did you try it?

Thank you for your reply. Yes, I plugged in the dock and tested it. I do get a new Ethernet interface (PCI Ethernet) and the USB stick I plugged in works too!

So check my 2nd comment: that's the official procedure (but for Ubuntu only).

So, I tried and did not manage to get it up and running. I followed all the steps including the Appendix A, as I have Secure Boot enabled. However, still nothing. whenever I try sudo systemctl start displaylink it results in an error that it is not installed. Then, I tried this https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/yxkm3w/comment/iy5mh3g/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button manual, but it does not work either. Could you help me figuring out where to start looking for errors?

I am asking myself why there does not exist a proper installation guide at the Github repository here https://github.com/displaylink-rpm/displaylink-rpm The insctuctions are very vague except of the commands in case of Secure Boot enabled. Do you have any hints on the procedure?

Sorry no idea. I don't have the hardware to do any test.

DisplayLink was acquired by Synaptics years ago and the updated drivers are now provided by them: https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads . Not really helpful because only Ubuntu is featured (the same drivers works for Debian and most Debian/Ubuntu derived distros).

That said, installing the drivers in the RPM format as mentioned in your own links should work but - https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1181617 - you need to manually sign the modules using your distro's recommended methods (preferred) or dsiable Secure Boot in UEFI (NOT recommended).

@ChanganAuto thank you for your message. I followed all the steps and actually signed the modules. However, it still does not work. I suspect that something is wrong with the needed evdi package or so. Whenever I try to startup displaylink there is an error that the package is not installed. So, something must be wrong, or not connected or whatever...do you have any hint where to start?
